# Postgresql createdb command hanging when running from groovy script

Tags: postgresql, groovy, postgresql-9.2

I've tried several different ways to get this to run, all unsuccessfully!

Currently, I have a groovy script that tries to execute the Postgresql (9.2) 'createdb' command like this:

```
def createDbCmdLine = "-p 5433 --encoding=UTF8 --template=template0 myDatabaseName"
ant.exec(executable:'fullpath/bin/createdb') {
    arg(line: "$createDbCmdLine")
    env(key:"PGPASSWORD", value:"myPassword")
}
```

However, this just hangs forever.  When I tried creating a string and executing:

```
["sh", "-c", theStringHere].execute()
```

the result was the same - hangs forever.  In this case though, I printed the string.  When I ran that on the command line (directly or via 'sh -c') it worked perfectly - after the command completes, I can enter postgresql via 'psql' do a \l and see the database created.

Anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely issue would be createdb not seeing the environment variable and hanging waiting for the password.

I think you have two options.  The first is to continue the shell escapes and try to use a .pgpass file, but the other is to connect to the postgres (or other existing db) and create the database manually.  To do this, issue the following SQL:

```
 CREATE DATABASE myDatabaseName WITH TEMPLATE template0 ENCODING utf8;
```